# Issue sending emails with swiftmailer bundle - Symfony2.1

Tags: php, smtp, symfony-2.1, swiftmailer

Trying to send an email with swiftmailer, with configuration of:

```
transport: smtp
host:      smtp.emailsrvr.com
user:      *user*
password:  *password*
```

I'm trying to test this from localhost, using xampp and symfony 2.1. Currently the error I get is this:

"Connection could not be established with host smtp.emailsrvr.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]"

The method I'm calling to send the emails looks like this:

```
/**
 * Send an email
 * @param type $data
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function sendMail($data)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject(isset($data['subject']) ? $data['subject'] : 'No subject')
            ->setFrom($data['from'])
            ->setTo($data['to'])
            ->setBody(
                $this->render('myBundle:emails:'.$data['view'].'.txt.twig',
                $data['viewData']));
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return true;
}
```

Is there maybe something in XAMPP that I need to set up before I can send emails? I've tried a few things, but so far nothing is working.

Comment: Have you tried with another transport, gmail for example? Just to discard if is a matter of swiftmailer or smtp/xampp

Comment: [Here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=477422) say to open port 25

Comment: Thanks, I have tried other transports, but none have worked so far. This is the one I need to be using, though, so that's not really an option anyway. But I'll try messing with the ports and let you know what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the ISP blocking certain ports, I wound up having to use port 587 for localhost, and we switched server providers as Bluehost blocks both 25 and 587. Hopefully this is helpful to anyone who runs into this same issue.